# MySQL Left Outer Join not returning NULL values for COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null

I am attempting to left outer join 2 tables: TABLE1 contains a list of users and TABLE2 contains a list of forms completed by users. I want to display the count of forms by user, created after a given date, where status equals COMPLETED.

The following query is working but not displaying NULL values (which I need):

```
select TABLE1.USERNAME, count(TABLE2.FORMS)
from TABLE1
left outer join TABLE2 on (TABLE2.USERID = TABLE1.USERID)
and TABLE2.STATUS = COMPLETED
where TABLE2.DATE > 20140801
group by TABLE1.USERNAME;
```

What do I need to do to include users with NULL counts i.e. no forms in TABLE2?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Comment: count() function never returns null value.If match is not found then it display 0 as result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to move the condition in the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
select TABLE1.USERNAME, count(TABLE2.FORMS)
from TABLE1 left outer join
     TABLE2
     on (TABLE2.USERID = TABLE1.USERID) and TABLE2.STATUS = COMPLETED and
        TABLE2.DATE > 20140801
group by TABLE1.USERNAME;
```

In rows that don't match, the `table2` columns are set to `NULL`.  That, in turn, causes your `where` clause to fail (because comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`, which is treated as false).

When using `left outer join`, filters on the *second* table go in the `on` clause.  Filters on the *first* table go in the `where` clause.

Comment: by far the best and simplest explanation on using the WHERE clause on left outer joined tables. Thank you!